# replacing/updating content of a website

Tags: ajax, html, jquery

I think the time has come to ask for help.Seven days of reading AJAX tutorials just got me frustrated, and i am more confused than ever. My goal is to change content dynamically and load (static) content after a click event.
Whats the best way(or at least a way) to replace content of a  after clicking on an  ? (It is not form-related )

Answer (score 0):

To replace the content within a static page, one way is use JSON object
For example:

1) Click on a HTML button, have an onClick event (javascript) associate with it.

2) Within that onClick event, set it up to do a xhrPost call (in this case, I use DOJO toolkit, you can use DOJO, YUI, JQuery etc

```
function refreshDataGrid(gridDesc, url) {
  dojo.xhrPost({
    url: unescape(url),
    handleAs : "json",
    sync: true,
    load: function (response, args) {
    if (response.success) { 
     dojo.byId('divSearchResultMessages').innerHTML = "";
     dojo.removeClass('divResults','hiddenField');
     dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({data:response.searchResults}));
    }else {
     dijit.byId('dg'+gridDesc).setStore(null);
     dojo.byId('divSearchResultMessages').innerHTML = "<div style='text-align:center' class='warning'><br><br>" + response.messages+"</div>";
     dojo.addClass('divResults','hiddenField');
   }
    return response;
            },
            error: function (exception, args) { 
                standby.hide();
                handleAjaxError2();
                return response;        
            }
        });     
    }
```

3) Once the request has send to server side (java) servletController, you can process the information pass from the javascript (as a request parameter) and return JSON object back to the servlet (front end) page

4) If everything is done correctly, you should see your page getting a dynamic data without refreshing the whole page.

There is a lot of AJAX tutorial that would help you establish what I've help. I hope this helps.

Ref:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-ground/

Comment: thanks very much for the quick response . I ll have to look it up since i dont use Dojo(i use jQuery).I ll tell you how it goes:-)

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery to perform .toggleVisibility amongst other actions on a layer that is already in your content.

Comment: ok, but i dont think this is an AJAX technique.
I really must insist on "content replacement" rather than "content hiding".
p.s.:It may be static content but its not located in the same page